Rollback transaction in Mikro-ORM for all updates and inserts
I am using Mikro-ORM.
I have an Entity:
@Entity({ tableName: 'students' })
@Unique({ properties: ['code'] })
export class StudentEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @Property()
  firstName: string;

  @Property()
  lastName: string;

  @Property({ nullable: true })
  code?: string;
}

I have a bunch of students that I want to write all at once or none at all and I want to notify the user on where the error occurred (by the row index).
I want to know that the code is unique and not already in the DB. I have the constraint to take care of that but I need to trigger it, so I guess I need to perform an actual INSERT on the DB for that to happen.
Hence, I am considering transactions.
await this.em.begin();
try {
  var row = 1;
  for (const data of entries) {
    const entity = this.studentsRepo.create({
      ...data
    });
    this.em.persist(entity);
    await this.em.commit(); // inside the for-loop
    row += 1;
  }
} catch (e) {
  await this.em.rollback();
  throw Error(`Something happened at row ${row}`);
}

This will only delete the last entry, the one where the error occurred, leaving the rest in the database.
How can I roll back everything while catching errors at the "row" level?

This thread answers the question:
https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/discussions/6268
